# Pandas: how to modify the style of only one bar in a multibar histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have generated this histogram:
[image]
I need to change the style of the orange bar in order to let the histogram understandable even to a person that prints it in grey-scale.

For example, I'd like to have it transparent, or barred. I cannot figure out how to customize the bars in the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = pd.read_csv('compare.csv', usecols=['a', 'b'])
mydict = {'75-80': [0, 0], '80-85': [0, 0], '85-90': [0, 0], '90-95': [0, 0], '95-100': [0, 0]}
mylist = list(dict.values())
# various operations to fill mylist
print(mylist) #Output: [[1, 0], [13, 0], [124, 11], [606, 52], [256, 937]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=mylist,
                 index=['75-80', '80-85', '85-90', '90-95', '95-100'],
                 columns=pd.Index(['a', 'b'],
                 )).round(2)
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15, 6), rot = 0)
```

Comment: The question is probably a duplicate, however, the answer over there is really hacky...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I failed to reproduce the answer in the duplicated question

Comment: It works and for me is acceptable, Thanks

Comment: Ok, in that case I guess closing is appropriate.